# Prevent users from logging support cases

Tags: validation

I've searched the internet and various SF documents but cannot find a solution -- is there a way to limit groups of users from being able to log a support case with Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

You can reach out to your Account Executive and provide the list of users who should be the only ones to log cases so that they can add them to the special handling instructions of your account. The salesforce support would action based on those given guidelines

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what level of support you have with SF, but from Knowledge Article Number: 000005588 titled [Why am I having problems logging a case using the Self-Service Portal?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005588&language=en_US),

> In order to use the salesforce Self-Service Portal to create/check cases you must be a listed as a salesforce contact. If you still are unable to log a case and view the Self Service Portal, check with your Premier Service Rep or log a case via phone with salesforce support to have "Self Service User" enabled for your user record.

I believe the above KB Article primarily applies to orgs which have Premiere or Premiere Plus level Support. If that's your situation, anyone who's not on your contact list would not be able to use the Self-Service Portal to create a case.

I also found Knowledge Article Number: 000123530 [How can I submit /create or update a case from Help & Training?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000123530&language=en_US). The first few steps listed are:

> 1. Click on the right top corner of your salesforce in Help & Training
> 2. Click on Contact Support
> 3. Fill in the information on New Case detail. You can add email addresses under Case collaborators section to involve more user in the
>      case and have them being part of the support resolution.
> 4. You can also access your open & closed cases from your Help & Training page. You can update or close your open cases in either of
>      the following 2 ways:
>
>    - Locate the "Quick Links" widget or
>    - The "My Cases" widget

From reading the last kk article, unless there's information your users don't have access to that Salesforce requires to complete a New Case Submission form, I don't see a means of preventing specific groups of users from creating new support cases through the Help link.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question is little old. I ran into the same issue where some of our users are logging cases directly with Salesforce. I found this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=replacing_online_help.htm&language=en_US&type=0) but didnt find useful (Let me know if it works for you). Other [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175489&language=en_US&type=1) I found is useful and works for me but this is only for your custom vf pages. where you need to add a css style to display:none for that link element.